# Expresso Store - Modify quantity in backend

Tags: expresso-store

When I want to modify quantity of products up or down in the backend I can change some of the items and some not.

If not possible the save button stays light-gray and nothing happens.

Any idea?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution.

The modification typ was 'Variation' and for one position the minimal order quantitiy was missing.

Thx